# How to properly refactor first phase of object initialisation in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

So I learned in Swift we should use two-phase initialisation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html

One of the rules is: "An initializer cannot call any instance methods, read the values of any instance properties, or refer to self as a value until after the first phase of initialization is complete."

This prevents placing chunks of code in instance methods, so I guess class methods should be used? What do you think? Any alternative solutions?

To illustrate what I mean here are 3 code samples:

Unrefactored code:

```
@objc class MYChatBarButton: UIBarButtonItem {

    let badgeLabel: UILabel


    init(target: AnyObject, selector: Selector) {

        let button = UIButton.buttonWithType(.Custom) as UIButton
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 35, 44)
        button.addTarget(target, action: selector, forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        button.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "chat_icon")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate), forState: .Normal)
        button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 7, bottom: 5, right: 0)

        badgeLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 15, 15))
        badgeLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        badgeLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        badgeLabel.textAlignment = .Center
        badgeLabel.text = "0"
        badgeLabel.userInteractionEnabled = false

        button.addSubview(badgeLabel)


        super.init(customView: button)


    }


}
```

The way I expected to do refactoring but it doesn't work:

```
@objc class MYChatBarButton: UIBarButtonItem {

    let badgeLabel: UILabel


    init(target: AnyObject, selector: Selector) {

        let button = createButton(target, selector: selector)
        createBadgeLabel()
        button.addSubview(badgeLabel)

        super.init(customView: button)


    }

    func createButton(target: AnyObject, selector: Selector) -> UIButton {
        let button = UIButton.buttonWithType(.Custom) as UIButton
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 35, 44)
        button.addTarget(target, action: selector, forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        button.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "chat_icon")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate), forState: .Normal)
        button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 7, bottom: 5, right: 0)
        return button
    }

    func createBadgeLabel() {
        badgeLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 15, 15))
        badgeLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        badgeLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        badgeLabel.textAlignment = .Center
        badgeLabel.text = "0"
        badgeLabel.userInteractionEnabled = false
    }

}
```

The way it should probably be done (but I don't like it so very much):

```
@objc class MYChatBarButton: UIBarButtonItem {

    let badgeLabel: UILabel


    init(target: AnyObject, selector: Selector) {

        let button = MYChatBarButton.createButton(target, selector: selector)
        badgeLabel = MYChatBarButton.createBadgeLabel()
        button.addSubview(badgeLabel)

        super.init(customView: button)


    }

    class func createButton(target: AnyObject, selector: Selector) -> UIButton {
        let button = UIButton.buttonWithType(.Custom) as UIButton
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 35, 44)
        button.addTarget(target, action: selector, forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        button.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "chat_icon")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate), forState: .Normal)
        button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 7, bottom: 5, right: 0)
        return button
    }

    class func createBadgeLabel() -> UILabel {
        let bl = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 15, 15))
        bl.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        bl.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        bl.textAlignment = .Center
        bl.text = "0"
        bl.userInteractionEnabled = false
    }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you like the class functions? They're exactly what you mean. Is there something else about it you don't like?

Comment: To play devils advocate, why do you need to refactor that code out of init? You will never re-set that button as it is "let."

Comment: What is the purpose of the refactor? As Acey says, why is it so important to not initialize, for example, badgeLabel in the init like the original code versus calling a method to do this? If you are re-using the code, it makes sense (eg. going to recall that). Also Acey's comment on `let` basically infers to why your 2nd code doesn't work for `createBadgeLabel`. As `badgeLabel` is a constant, you cannot assign it again. Any constant value must be defined by the time `init` is done.

Comment: Personally, I think it's reasonable to re-factor code just to split a method that does a couple of separate things into two separate, isolated, well-named methods. Whether you're going to re-use it or not, it still makes it easier to read, understand and change.

Comment: Refactoring code like this is just a good coding practice and it makes code itself more understandable and readable. Its just that using class methods doesn't look so neat.

Answer (score 2):

At least, you can isolate the `badgeLabel` creation:

```
@objc class MYChatBarButton: UIBarButtonItem {

    let badgeLabel: UILabel = {
        let bl = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 15, 15))
        bl.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        bl.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        bl.textAlignment = .Center
        bl.text = "0"
        bl.userInteractionEnabled = false
        return bl
    }()

    let button: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton.buttonWithType(.Custom) as UIButton
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 35, 44)
        button.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "chat_icon")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate), forState: .Normal)
        button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 7, bottom: 5, right: 0)
        return button
    }()

    init(target: AnyObject, selector: Selector) {
        button.addTarget(target, action: selector, forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        button.addSubview(badgeLabel)
        super.init(customView: button)
    }
```

I don't know how to do this without property.

Comment: Thanks for this one. This solves if you have instance vars for all object you wish to create. But sometimes you don't need instance vars.

Comment: Also both lines in init method button. ... should go below super.init line. The way you have done it would initialise both variables two times. First time you access var before super.init line and second time at super.init. Swift has one rule not to use any instance method or variables or constants before super.init

Comment: Yeah, you need property. If you don't like that, I think, you have to use class method or global function. BTW, you can access stored properties **before** `super.init`, as long as it's declared in that class itself.

Comment: I just had a bad experience with stored properties used before super.init. You can put breakpoint inside property block I and you will see it is initialised two times if you use it before super.init. In my example badgeLabel was created two times, I displayed first created instance on screen, but was later trying to update text on second instance ... so no updates on screen.

Comment: It seems, something wrong in `UIBarButtonItem`. `super.init(customView:)` creates **new** instance. the workaround would be: `super.init(); self.customView = button`. But I've not confirmed that works...